# Quickly input frequent used phrase by choose-and-paste

Tags: automation

Is there any application that can enhance the clipboard, so that I can quickly input some frequent used phrase by choose-and-paste?

Use case:

I need to input my email address to a field in an application. I recall my frequent used phrases list (by some kind of operation), choose my email address, then it is pasted into the field.

Comment: Both SmartClipboard and Quickcopy fits me. SmartClipboard can paste phone number or email address chose from my contacts as well. But its ad is annoying, it's too close to the buttons I often press the ad by mistake. So I finally choose Quickcopy.

Comment: use NATIVE CLIPBOARD., it is the best to copy and paste, TEMPLATE option
u can use it in SMS, WHATSAPP, TEST Editors.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I use [Quickcopy](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quickcopy/be.vbsteven.quickcopy) - It may be as close as you will get to your ideal. The only part it will not do is automatically paste into the field you want it to, but it does provide quick access.

Answer (score 2):

You could try Smart Clipboard: http://www.appbrain.com/app/smart-clipboard/net.xdevelop.cp it claims to do just what you are asking.

Personally I use Uber Keyboard: http://www.appbrain.com/app/uber-keyboard-%28text-voice%29/com.pwnwithyourphone.talktomekbd It give you suggestions while you type which I usually ignore but it also let's you set custom mappings.  So I set it up so the 1st two letters of my email are mapped to my full email address so when I type in mw it shows my full email as a suggestion so I can insert it without having to open another app.  I've set a bunch of other custom mappins as well for commonly entered things.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the creator of [Clipper](http://rojekti.fi/clipper), a free clipboard manager app. In addition to the clipboard history feature, you can also store *snippets*, which is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try 
[clipNote](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.esoco-android-clipboard-xCxD.aspx)