# How do I get quick access to common text snippets?

Tags: applications, keyboard

When filling out an online shopping form the other day via my browser, it sucked that I needed to manually type my email address, street address, postal code, etc.  Even credit card number (though I realize there are security implications there).

Is there a way to store commonly used snippets of text somewhere for quick and easy cut & paste?  Perhaps something integrated via a soft keyboard and key combos?

This relates a bit to [Share (through share menu) directly to own email address](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6100/share-through-share-menu-directly-to-own-email-address), but I want my email address to be accessible from any application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickly input frequent used phrase by choose-and-paste](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3117/quickly-input-frequent-used-phrase-by-choose-and-paste)

Comment: It does sound like both your initial question and your example of how you'd like to use it sound exactly the same (but worded slightly differently) as that previous question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3117/quickly-input-frequent-used-phrase-by-choose-and-paste

Comment: The questions are very similar but looking for a solution to enter an email address vs a solution to enter all form data including secure data like a credit card number is a distinction that I think is sufficiently different to warrant a separate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would put it into the keyboard's user dictionary.

There are a few clipboard/snippet manager application, you might be interested if you need to store longer texts:

- [Clipper](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.rojekti.clipper)
- [Text Snippet Lite IME](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appspot.gsjavadev.android.textsnippetslite)

Comment: Clipper seems like a nice solution.

Answer (score 5):

For quick access to your email address I agree with Lie Ryan, entering it into your user dictionary will bring it up as an auto suggestion as you type, however I wouldn't do this for more sensitive information.

**For a more secure and even faster method I'd recommend using [Dolphin Browser HD](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) with the [LastPass plugin](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lastpass.lpdolphin).**  LastPass lets you securely save user login and password info, as well as different profiles with addresses and credit card numbers.  With this setup **you can fill out a whole form with one click.**  If you don't use Dolphin browser you can accomplish the same thing with the auto-fill bookmarklets that LastPass offers.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in my answer on this question

[Application to switch among multiple running applications](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10310/application-to-switch-among-multiple-running-applications/10331#10331)

Additionally, Smart Keyboard Pro does text macros.