# Keyboard Macros

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to have keyboard macros? Like on iPhone if you type lol it automatically converts it into laugh out loud? Couldn't find it on my phone for multiple hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get quick access to common text snippets?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7586/how-do-i-get-quick-access-to-common-text-snippets)

Comment: @AlEverett Quite a different scenario, but I suppose the answer could also be useful. Leaving this Open, just in case.